# When I import TPotClassifier, it gets an attributeError about numpy. Specifically np.float doesn't exist. What am I missing?

Tags: python, numpy, automl, tpot

Here is the full error traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\github\beluga3\SCRATCHPAPER_6.py", line 4, in <module>
    from MLModule.AI.featuretoolstpot.ml_framework import MyMLModeler
  File "C:\Users\david\github\beluga3\MLModule\AI\featuretoolstpot\ml_framework.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tpot import TPOTClassifier
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tpot\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .tpot import TPOTClassifier, TPOTRegressor
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tpot\tpot.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .base import TPOTBase
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tpot\base.py", line 70, in <module>
    from .builtins import CombineDFs, StackingEstimator
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tpot\builtins\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .one_hot_encoder import OneHotEncoder, auto_select_categorical_features, _transform_selected
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tpot\builtins\one_hot_encoder.py", line 136, in <module>
    class OneHotEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tpot\builtins\one_hot_encoder.py", line 216, in OneHotEncoder
    def __init__(self, categorical_features='auto', dtype=np.float,
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 284, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'. Did you mean: 'cfloat'?
```

As you can see, when it tries to instantiate the class OneHotEncoder, the class has one input parameter of dtype, and it uses np.float.  But apparently numpy has no such attribute.  I checked all my dependencies, and made sure everything was upgrade.

I'm running Python 3.10.2

Any help would be great.

Comment: As far as I can see, this error is correct.  numpy does not have a `float` type.  Instead, it has `float16`, `float32`, and `float64`.  This seems like an error in the `tpot` package.

Comment: okay. thanks I'll report it to the tpot dev team.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when using *tpot* with *numpy 1.24*. This version of *numpy* has removed type aliases, like `np.float`. This was already declared as deprecated since version 1.20, and now it has been removed.

The developers of tpot should modify their code to avoid this issue. But, as a solution for the time being you can avoid the issue by simply using a version of numpy <1.24

More info on this issue and how to fix this in your own code can be found [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fix-attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-float-d7d68c5a4971).

Comment: Thank you. I downgraded it to 1.22.4 and I think it worked because I got a different error this time lol

Comment: Good. By the way, I wrote you should use numpy<1.3,  but I meant numpy<1.24, so you can use 1.23. I 've just edited my answer